# How to make a debug build of monero on mac os x?

Tags: source, macos, build

I am able to compile monero on mac os x v 10.10.5 using the directions found here:

https://github.com/monero-project/monero

specifically

> brew tap sammy007/cryptonight
>
> brew install monero --build-from-source

But I would like to make a build that I can debug with gdb.

What is the easiest way to do this on mac os x?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend following the instructions to build from source (not using the  brew package). https://github.com/monero-project/monero#compiling-monero-from-source.

Once you have the dependencies installed you just `make debug` in the cloned repository directory.